# How do you interact with this json in angular using rxjs?

Tags: json

Here is the Below json data I am looking to parse. I am not sure how to best use this data. For example what is the best way to get Information of Meta Data?

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-09-17 16:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "1min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (1min)": {
        "2019-09-17 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "220.7700",
            "2. high": "220.8300",
            "3. low": "220.6100",
            "4. close": "220.6500",
            "5. volume": "366142"
        },
        "2019-09-17 15:59:00": {
            "1. open": "220.6500",
            "2. high": "220.7900",
            "3. low": "220.6500",
            "4. close": "220.7650",
            "5. volume": "118750"
        },
        "2019-09-17 15:58:00": {
            "1. open": "220.6200",
            "2. high": "220.6850",
            "3. low": "220.6000",
            "4. close": "220.6500",
            "5. volume": "70167"
        },
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen .What is the best way to interact with the data that is returned by this api??

Comment: I'm sorry, must be not awake yet. JSON actually looks fine (except for the fact that it's cut off, but I assume that you just pasted the first part).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen All good. How would I use it because there is a space there?

Comment: Have to use square brackets to access the value: `data['Meta Data']`

Comment: E.g. `data['Meta Data']['1. Information']`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thank you so much for the help man spent a few hours struggling through this. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JavaScript object is saved to some variable names `data`, then you can get the information of "Meta Data" using the following syntax:

```
data["Meta Data"]
```

Hope this helps :)